# How can I determine if a given git hash exists on a given branch?

Tags: git

Background: I use an automated build system which takes a git hash as input, as well as the name of the branch on which that hash exists, and builds it.  However, the build system uses the hash alone to check out the code and build it -- it simply stores the branch name, as given, in the build DB metadata.

I'm worried about developers accidentally providing the wrong branch name when they kick off a build, causing confusion when people are looking through the build history.

So how can I confirm, before passing along the hash and branch name to the build system, that the given hash does in fact come from the given branch?

Comment: why do you need the branch name? it seems an extra useless piece of info to the build system. And I don't really see how would it be any use to a developer reading build logs.

Comment: You would need the branch name in case your workflow has, I don't know, a develop and master branch used for deployment and you want to know if commits got into any particular one? By the way, please accept the real answer.

Comment: @Pinko I think the selected answer should be [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2444924/161278). Since it has a lot more votes and much simpler due to the use of native git functionality.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You can ask `git branch` directly which branches contain the commit in question:

```
% git branch -a --contains 4f08c85ad
* master
  remotes/origin/bug_872
  remotes/origin/bug_898
  remotes/origin/master
```

Comment: Remove `-a` option to list from your local branch only

Comment: A specific branch could be used instead of `-a` e.g. `$ git branch develop --contains 4f08c85ad`

Answer (score 8):

Hmm, this use of a branch name seems fishy. As in Dustin's answer, there may be multiple branches that contain a commit. Why is any one of those branch names better than another for this purpose?

---

If you only care about one specific branch, you could compute the “merge base” between the branch and the commit.

In the following diagrams, the commit to build is `C`, the tip of the claimed branch is `T`, and the merge base is labeled with `M` above it.

- If `M` equals `C` equals `T`, then the the commit to build is the tip of the claimed branch.

  ```
                   M
                   ↓
    o--o--o--o--o--x  branch  # x is both C and T
  ```
- If `M` equals `C`, then the tip of the claimed branch is a descendent of the commit to build.

  ```
          M
          ↓
    o--o--C--o--o--T  branch
  ```
- If `M` equals `T`, then the commit to build is a descendent of the tip of the claimed branch.

  ```
          M
          ↓
    o--o--T           branch
           \
            o--o--C
  ```
- If `M` equals something else, then `C` is a descendent of some ancestor of `T`.

  ```
          M
          ↓
    o--o--o--o--o--T  branch
           \
            o--o--C
  ```
- If there is no `M`, then the commit to build is not related to the claimed branch.

  ```
    o--o--o--o--o--T branch

    o--o--o--o--C
  ```

You can make this check like this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# Usage: is-ancestor-of <branch> <commit>

if test $# -ne 2; then
    echo "$0"': invalid arguments'
    exit 128
fi
claimed_branch="$1"
commit="$2"

merge_base="$(git merge-base "$commit" "$claimed_branch")" &&
  test -n "$merge_base" &&
  test "$merge_base" = "$(git rev-parse --verify "$commit")" &&
  exit 0

echo "$commit is not an ancestor of $claimed_branch" 1>&2
exit 1
```

The above script does not actually require or check that the ‘branch’ argument is a branch (it could be any commit-ish). To check that something is actually a branch, you might use something like this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# Usage: is-branch <branch>

if test $# -ne 1; then
    echo "$0"': invalid arguments'
    exit 128
fi
branch="$1"

# check various branch hierarchies, adjust as needed
git show-ref --verify refs/heads/"$branch" ||
git show-ref --verify refs/remotes/"$branch" || {
    echo "not a branch name: $branch" 1>&2
    exit 1
}
```

So you could use them together to verify that something is a branch and that a certain commit is in that branch:

```
is-branch "$claimed_branch" && is-ancestor-of "$claimed_branch" "$commit_to_build"
```

Comment: Why the heck would you do this when git has a built-in better solution? Why on earth was this ridiculously convoluted answer accepted when it is clearly not the best? I wasted time sifting through this instead of scrolling down to the answer that should be at the top. Wow...

Comment: Is it possible for SO admins to change the accepted answer? If so that should be done in this case.

Comment: @SpencerWilliams Always give people the benefit of the doubt. The answer was most likely accepted because the `--contains` option to `git branch` was only added in git v1.5.4 (September 2010) whereas this answer was given in March 2010, so at that time it *was* the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

One possible **non-solution** would be to parse the result of:

```
$ git reflog show myBranch
```

And see if your hash is in it.

```
C:\Prog\Git\tests\rep\main>git reflog show patches
786a190 patches@{0}: rebase finished: refs/heads/patches onto 74630b983db476c323b1d3f6771e57484551240e
8448d0f patches@{1}: master~1: updating HEAD
74630b9 patches@{2}: commit: test2
1e73e36 patches@{3}: branch: Created from master
```

I keep this as a Community Wiki answer to remember [Igor Zevaka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/129404/igor-zevaka) and [Chris Johnsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/193688/chris-johnsen)'s comments:

> Would that work after a clone?
> Pretty sure your reflog starts after you clone a remote. So if a branch had a commit before the clone, it wouldn't show up in the reflog.
>
> There are also problems with pushes, rebases, fetches (for ‘remote tracking’ branches), and pulls (either merge or rebase type) where only the new tip commit ends up the reflog.
> Also, reflogs are disabled by default in bare repositories (the most common destination for pushes).
> Also, if “cheating” is a problem, it is just a matter of editing a text file to add or delete reflog entries, but it is a bigger ordeal to alter the history graph itself.

---

Do not forget [`git reflog exists`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) which can check if a ref has a reflog.

With Git 2.36 (Q2 2022), "[`git reflog`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3ff8cbfe8a333f55931fa9b588f106e060a67079/Documentation/git-reflog.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog))</sup> command now uses parse-options API to parse its command line options.

See [commit 840344d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/840344db7578a794fd25c44587e4a08dfe4f41cc) (28 Mar 2022) by [SZEDER Gábor (`szeder`)](https://github.com/szeder).
See [commit fbc15b1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fbc15b13f7380ee7b52fdcb467c3438c569fd5de), [commit e3c3675](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e3c3675801f6d7494ac11e772e848981d1e158b4), [commit a34393f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a34393f5f8152ad8bdbf15bccffc2be12a9a19ca), [commit cbe4852](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cbe485298bf06a4e6377f5a692c82a9e3ad38069), [commit 1e91d3f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1e91d3faf6c6de7667603c9c81252161ee70d7b9), [commit d3ab1a5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d3ab1a5fcf3db26ba36fb5be07365908f7906ddb), [commit 5f9b64a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5f9b64a6c26552af2c3c57ea37f308537dc5bee9), [commit 03df6cb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/03df6cb833a21e924b02af58df76d93a8e0d9648) (17 Mar 2022) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3ff8cbf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3ff8cbfe8a333f55931fa9b588f106e060a67079), 04 Apr 2022)</sup>

> ### [`reflog exists`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a34393f5f8152ad8bdbf15bccffc2be12a9a19ca): use `parse_options()` API
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> Change the "reflog exists" command added in [afcb2e7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/afcb2e7a3b855887e79d1ee6d70ec80ab6456a64) ("`git-reflog`: add exists command", 2015-07-21, Git v2.6.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b6d323f1646d7204fc6693071e5be84377ece70b) listed in [batch #1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eb67052b132cc6ebfeed78fc74d2e4ef40390e7f)) to use `parse_options()` instead of its own custom command-line parser.
> This continues work started in [33d7bdd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/33d7bdd64592d6dc86583a817719f91d7344e958) (`builtin/reflog.c`: use parse-options api for expire, 2022-01-06, Git v2.36.0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1b4d9b4512ea5a4d76ac4af40e9a4ed4729403e3) listed in [batch #1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/38062e73e009f27ea192d50481fcb5e7b0e9d6eb)) ([`builtin/reflog.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a34393f5f8152ad8bdbf15bccffc2be12a9a19ca/builtin/reflog.c): use parse-options api for expire, delete subcommands, 2022-01-06).
>
> As a result we'll understand the `--end-of-options` synonym for --, so let's test for that.

---

"[`git reflog`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/dbffe54f8a49b167ebe44eee57a40b29dcb4871a/Documentation/git-reflog.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog))</sup> expire `--single-worktree` has been broken for the past 20 months or so, which has been corrected with Git 2.43 (Q4 2023).

See [commit 26d4c51](https://github.com/git/git/commit/26d4c51d36a1f4f9463eb694758474243d7877e6) (28 Oct 2023) by [René Scharfe (`rscharfe`)](https://github.com/rscharfe).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit dbffe54](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dbffe54f8a49b167ebe44eee57a40b29dcb4871a), 07 Nov 2023)</sup>

> ### [`reflog`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/26d4c51d36a1f4f9463eb694758474243d7877e6): fix expire --single-worktree
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: René Scharfe</sup>

> [33d7bdd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/33d7bdd64592d6dc86583a817719f91d7344e958) (`builtin/reflog.c`: use parse-options api for expire, 2022-01-06, Git v2.36.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1b4d9b4512ea5a4d76ac4af40e9a4ed4729403e3) listed in [batch #1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/38062e73e009f27ea192d50481fcb5e7b0e9d6eb)) ([`builtin/reflog.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/26d4c51d36a1f4f9463eb694758474243d7877e6/builtin/reflog.c): use parse-options api for expire, delete subcommands, 2022-01-06) broke the option `--single-worktree` of [`git reflog`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/26d4c51d36a1f4f9463eb694758474243d7877e6/Documentation/git-reflog.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog))</sup> expire and added a non-printable short flag for it, presumably by accident.
> While before it set the variable `"all_worktrees"` to 0, now it sets it to 1, its default value.
> `--no-single-worktree` is required now to set it to 0.
>
> Fix it by replacing the variable with one that has the opposite meaning, to avoid the negation and its potential for confusion.
> The new variable `"single_worktree"` directly captures whether `--single-worktree` was given.
>
> Also remove the unprintable short flag SOH (start of heading) because it is undocumented, hard to use and is likely to have been added by mistake in connection with the negation bug above.

Comment: Would that work after a clone? Pretty sure your reflog starts after you clone a remote. So if a branch had a commit before the clone, it wouldn't show up in the reflog.

Comment: Right, @Igor Zevaka. There are also problems with pushes and rebases (where only the new tip commit ends up the reflog). Also reflogs are disabled by default in bare repositories (the most common destination for pushes). Also, if “cheating” is a problem, it is just a matter of editing a text file to add or delete reflog entries, but it is a bigger ordeal to alter the history graph itself.

Comment: Note to self: see also [commit cbf498e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cbf498eb534c5a41c2c4fa5681d18e22d93b8fb4), Git 2.44, Q1 2024.